# How to pass parameters in mouse events bindings

Tags: angular

I render table and add (mouseenter) event for every cell with parameters based on row and column index.

```
<table>
 <tr *ngFor="let row of rows; let rowIndex = index;">
  <td *ngFor="let column of columns; let columnIndex = index;"
   (mouseenter)="mouseEnterHandler(rowIndex, columnIndex)">
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>

mouseEnterHandler(rowIndex, columnIndex) {}
```

However this cause a performance issue and that's why I wanted to run mouseenter outside angular using ngZone.

```
this.zone.runOutsizeAngular(() => {
 this.element.nativeElement.addEventListener('mouseenter', this.mouseEnterHandler.bind(this));
});
```

But now I will not have access for current mouseenter row and column index. Is is possible to get these parameters during mouse enter event?

Comment: Create a directive that does what you want and bind the directive to the `<td>` element.

Answer (score -1):

In your function you can do something like this

```js
mouseEnterHandler(rowIndex, columnIndex){
  console.log(rowIndex);
  console.log(columnIndex);
}
```